# How to reference textbox in a MS Access form in SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to find a way to make SQL pick up the data in a textbox on the form in MS Access. If there is any other way around this I'm sure I can do that as I have spent so much time on it already!

In a textbox on the form is where you write down the primary key your using then click submit. It would run the SQL, but the issue is I can't find how to get primary key in there. It's working as if I put it in '' then the whole SQL works. That's only if there is one choice but I want to be able to put loads of possible numbers in.

I have tried:

```
textbox.text, [forms]![form1]![textbox], form1.textbox,
```

Here's my current code:

```
Dim strQuery As String  
strQuery = "UPDATE cwsmeriaid SET Pwyntiau = Pwyntiau + 1 WHERE Rhif_Yswiriant_Gwladol = Forms![frm_Archebiad]![rhifYswiriant]" 
DoCmd.RunSQL strQuery
```

Comment: Looks like you are saving cumulative (aggregate) data. This is usually a poor design. Calculate aggregate data when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't enclose variables in quotes. Referencing form control is a variable. Concatenate variables.

```
Dim strQuery As String  
strQuery = "UPDATE cwsmeriaid SET Pwyntiau = Pwyntiau + 1 WHERE Rhif_Yswiriant_Gwladol = " & Forms![frm_Archebiad]![rhifYswiriant]
DoCmd.RunSQL strQuery
```

If you want to avoid warning popups with action SQL, either turn warnings off then on with DoCmd.SetWarnings [True/False] or use:

```
CurrentDb.Execute strQuery
```